# Spring Boot + Primefaces default URL redirection

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces, spring-boot

I've setup Spring Boot + Primefaces + embedded Tomcat project and so far I'm satisfied, particulary with facelets recognizing Spring Beans and Services (SpringBeanFacesELResolver).
Now I would like to configure application so that base URL would translate into faces base URL.
For example: http://localhost:8080/ to be redirected to http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml

Can someone provide an example how to configure this in Spring Boot?

Comment: There's quite some ambiguity in the question, but given the concrete example, you basically want to achieve the same as `<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>` in a regular `web.xml` file?

Comment: Yes, that is it. I believe I've found the answer with the help of https://github.com/benneq and will provide an answer but you are welcome to provide a better/more suitable solution if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of https://github.com/benneq
I've found the solution...
I defined new @Controller Spring Bean and a method which redirects blank path to index.xhtml:

```
@Controller
public class RedirectController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(RedirectController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String baseUrlRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        return "redirect:" + request.getRequestURL().append("index.xhtml").toString();
    }
}
```